# Api call in android and receive this error using Retrofit 2 :Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://api.com/video/list-video.php}

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2, response

[image: log response]I am getting null response in place of value.

My json response is

```
{
    "resonse": {
        "status": 200,
        "result": [
            {
                "video_id": "3c19979979",
                "video_title": "Sushil Kumar Modi press conference after serial bomb blasts at Modi rally in Patna",
                "video_description": "BJP at Patna serial blast in Bihar, Nitish government has stood in the dock. Former Deputy Chief Minister Sushil Kumar Modi said the blasts Narendra Modi were targeted. He said that Nitish Kumar look Modi as the enemy.<br />\r\n",
                "video_poster": "https://vbcdn.com/cdn/download/2013102913830306761810268995.jpg",
                "video_duration": "02:02",
                "video_category": "News/Politics",
    }
  ]}
}
```

Retrofit client :

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        }).build();
       if (retrofit==null)
       retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .client(client)
               .build();
        return retrofit;
```

API CLIENT :

```
  @Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
    @POST("video/list-video.php")
    Call<ResponseVideoList> getVideoListFromSearchText(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
```

POJO class is:

```
public class ResponseVideoList implements  Serializable{


    @SerializedName("resonse")
    @Expose
    private Resonse resonse;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -2645239251698186770L;

    public Resonse getResonse() {
        return resonse;
    }

    public void setResonse(Resonse resonse) {
        this.resonse = resonse;
    }


    public class Resonse implements Serializable
    {

        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private String status;
        @SerializedName("result")
        @Expose
        private List<VIdeoItem> result = null;
        private final static long serialVersionUID = -350882274147346830L;

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public List<VIdeoItem> getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public void setResult(List<VIdeoItem> result) {
            this.result = result;
        }

    }

    }
```

Whenever I call the api , the statuscode is 200 but the response body is always coming as null.
the message i received is this :

Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://api.com/video/list-video.php}

Any help or suggestion is appreciated .

Comment: Have you tried using POSTMAN also?

Comment: yes it's working there. @sushildlh

Comment: Why you sending JSON object? Just try to make POJO for your request and try to hit it.

Comment: because i have to send body and headers in the POST method. the api is designed that way.and this is th e object i need to send {
    "param": {
       "max_results": 100,
        "search": "modi"
    }
}

Comment: make POJO of this and send using @Body replace JSOn Object with this POJO class.

Comment: is there any specific reason? i sent the data like this in another api call that was working

Comment: If you are using this `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`. It converts your request and response into an object form JSON. That is the only reason I am giving you a suggestion. All other things look good for me in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197726/discussion-between-sushrita-and-sushildlh).

Answer (score 0):

Just for new people who comes here with this error..  it can also happens when your data classes (model) does not correspond to the json you are consuming.

You can validate this by setting the onResponse() method from Retrofit to Any (kotlin) or to an Object (java)

```
   @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
        Log.d("zzz", "debug this line and check if response have ur object");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the returned JSON is not well formatted (unless you cropped the file to paste it here...)[image]

I used [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate it

Answer (score -1):

On first look your json seems wrong theres an additional ",", after "video_category": "News/Politics", <--- maybe thats the problem

```
Btw i would do my pojo like this
```

i used this site to create it automatically http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

you can always use this site to validate your JSON https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
-----------------------------------ResponseVideoList.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ResponseVideoList{

@SerializedName("resonse")
@Expose
private Resonse resonse;

public Resonse getResonse() {
return resonse;
}

public void setResonse(Resonse resonse) {
this.resonse = resonse;
}

}
-----------------------------------Resonse.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Resonse {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Integer status;
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private List<Result> result = null;

public Integer getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
this.status = status;
}

public List<Result> getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
this.result = result;
}

}
-----------------------------------Result.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Result {

@SerializedName("video_id")
@Expose
private String videoId;
@SerializedName("video_title")
@Expose
private String videoTitle;
@SerializedName("video_description")
@Expose
private String videoDescription;
@SerializedName("video_poster")
@Expose
private String videoPoster;
@SerializedName("video_duration")
@Expose
private String videoDuration;
@SerializedName("video_category")
@Expose
private String videoCategory;

public String getVideoId() {
return videoId;
}

public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
this.videoId = videoId;
}

public String getVideoTitle() {
return videoTitle;
}

public void setVideoTitle(String videoTitle) {
this.videoTitle = videoTitle;
}

public String getVideoDescription() {
return videoDescription;
}

public void setVideoDescription(String videoDescription) {
this.videoDescription = videoDescription;
}

public String getVideoPoster() {
return videoPoster;
}

public void setVideoPoster(String videoPoster) {
this.videoPoster = videoPoster;
}

public String getVideoDuration() {
return videoDuration;
}

public void setVideoDuration(String videoDuration) {
this.videoDuration = videoDuration;
}

public String getVideoCategory() {
return videoCategory;
}

public void setVideoCategory(String videoCategory) {
this.videoCategory = videoCategory;
}

}
```

Comment: it's not the complete json object I have just given it for reference.